# A question about n-dimensional Lesbegue measure

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

This is the p.70 of Folland Real analysis. It says that the completion of $m^n$ on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is equal to the completion of $m^n$ on $\mathcal{L}^n$. But Why do they agree? Could anyone explain?

Comment: A product of subsets of sets of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of a product of sets of measure zero, i.e. a subset of a set of measure zero.

Comment: At least it's still defined in Euclidean space. On manifolds with boundary,it really gets gnarly to define..........lol